# UIImageView Stretched vertically with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have `UIImageView` inside a `scrollview`. I have fixed the width of `uiimageview` to screen width. Now If I display a Larger Image, Since width is fixed, The image seem very stretched vertically.

[image]

If I use aspect fit:

```
imageViewTest.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Its undesirable result. Since I want to display orignal image.

Will be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: show us how do you want it originally ?

Comment: Please show your stroyBoard

Comment: "Also I am unable to find the bounds of image." Really? Why is that?

Comment: UIImageView just like UILabel and UIButton will have intrinsic content size. i.e. The size of image view will be the size of the image you set it with. But you have set your width constraint for image view here that's why it doesn't expand in terms of width however, the height constraint is not set, that's why the image view height will be height of image set and hence it expands in terms of height. Please set height constraint by setting height or using aspect ration constraint.

Comment: Also check my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544314/using-uiimageview-together-with-constraints/26544962#26544962

Comment: @matt If i use aspect fit for small image then image view is bigger and the image lies inside the imageview leaving space on sides

Comment: @mountain If you want the small image to fill all of the imageview try using .ScaleAspectFill for the content mode.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the **bottom** `constraint`.
2. Add a **height** `constraint`

[image]

1. Make an outlet of height constraint called: **constraintImageViewHeight**
2. Update the value of height constraint
3. Write this in **viewDidlayoutSubviews**

   ```
   -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
      [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
      [self calculateSizeForImageViewWith:testImage];
   }

   -(void)calculateSizeForImageViewWith:(UIImage *)img {
          float orignalWidth = img.size.width;
          float orignalHeight = img.size.height;

          float change = _imageViewDetail.frame.size.width;

          if (orignalWidth > 0) {
               float resizedAspectHeight = (orignalHeight * change)/orignalWidth;
               _constraintImageViewHeight.constant = resizedAspectHeight;
          } else {
              _constraintImageViewHeight.constant = 0;
            }
     }
   ```